# In iOS , What functions are running before the launch screen shows

Tags: ios, launch

Sometimes , when I click my app icon on desktop , it keeps highlighted for a period of time , 1~2 seconds , then the app opens and shows the launch screen.
I've no idea how to decrease the waiting time.

So I want to know in this period of time , what did the app do ? 
What functions are running before the launch screen shows ?

Comment: "desktop"?  Confused...

Comment: It means on simulator

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you are doing a lot in the `viewDidLoad` function of your initial viewController of your main storyboard. This will cause the launch screen to stay on screen until that functionality has finished.

You can fix this by putting that functionality into a background thread if it's not essential that it has finished before the viewController is presented.

Comment: In my opinion ,  the initial viewcontroller's `viewDidLoad` method runs after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions , which controls the launch screen show time . But my app are slow before the launch screen shows up.

Comment: Yes `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` does run before `viewDidLoad` but the very first `viewDidLoad` of your app is taken into account for the launch screen. I wrote an app a couple of months ago where I had the exact same issue and by thinning out that `viewDidLoad` the issue was fixed.

Comment: You'll need to thin out both functions, make sure that you're only doing what is 100% essential in those functions for the app to work. If you can, do some things on a background thread or asynchronously and it will start much faster

Answer (score 0):

Check `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` Method, if you have kept any timer there.

Generally it is an OS issue if it happens rarely, however if it happens every time you open the app, it has to be issue in following methods:

`applicationWillEnterForeground`

`applicationDidBecomeActive`

Comment: deleted the code  in 'applicationWillEnterForeground' and 'applicationDidBecomeActive' and tried some times,    runs well , but need more tests

Answer (score 0):

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions calls first of all. So make sure that you have made all the processing task on background threads. So that it will not block the main threads and calls the makeKeyAndVisible function on the Application to launch the app fast. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are doing some time consuming task on app startup - viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear delegate methods....
Do any time consuming task on the viewDidAppear also it would be great to do it on different thread(if not a UI related stuff).